# How to write multiple matrices to a text file in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I have a for loop creating a matrix every time and I need to write all the matrices to a text file

I used np.savetxt()in the for loop, but in the end, the textfile only shows the last matrix I created.

Does anyone know what happened?

```
file = open("newfile.txt", "w")
for i in range (0,5):
    matrix = numpy.zeros((5, 5)) 
    np.savetxt(file, matrix)
file.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you append to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You need use `ba` other than `w` when you append a numpy array into a csv file. 
`b` is binary mode 
Without `b` your code will have type error.
Tested on python3.5

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the file in append mode:

```
file = open("newfile.txt", "a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Flag "w" causes file to be overwitten, you should use "a", for appending.